# Unable to resolve dependency

Tags: android-studio

when build , show this error :

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could
>   not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just add `google()` under repositories as highlighted in attached picture to your project gradle, as google has move its repositories to maven you have to add this way, hope this helps you!!! or read this official doc [Support Library Setup](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html)
[image]

Another nice asnwer by Gabriele Mariotti [Using google() as a repository doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45766686/using-google-as-a-repository-doesnt-work)