# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

I have upgraded to API 27 and build tools. Previously I was using API 22.

after upgrading to SDK 27 I got error that I have to use support library similar to level 27. I have downloaded Support repository version 47.0.0 through SDK manager and finally this is my gradle setting. What should I do to resolve the following error:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sample.app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

> Error:(23, 13) Failed to resolve:
>   com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1

Comment: set * targetSdkVersion 27*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49854833/unable-to-resolve-dependency/49857491#49857491

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you get any solution, Ali?

Comment: I didn't test the answers to this question. I have just changed my codes without using of support package! @NasserTahani

Comment: This solution solved for Ionic 3 ---> https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-3-resolve-execution-failed-for-task-appprocessdebugresources/

Answer (score 7):

In your project build.gradle, change the sequence of repositories, make google() the first.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just change your dependencies version name same as below

```
dependencies {

        compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'

        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'

    }
```

and also add

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To all Ionic / Cordova users having this issue, the solution that worked for me was to edit the file: `platforms/android/project.properties`:

Then remove this line: `com.android.support:support-v4:26.+` and edit `target=` to `android-27`

Comment: am using capacitor i cant find `android/project.properties` file in the android folder

Answer (score 0):

try to
change:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sample.app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I fixed that error by just adding `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }` to section `buildscript => repositories` and also to section `allprojects => repositories` in root project file build.gradle. Simple conservative solution... no dependencies version changing or upgrading android studio. It is for older gradle versions (<4) where `google()` and `implementation` is not available.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this will fix it but

> 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation'

Try:
`implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'`

Instad of:
`compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'`